# For some reason my background image isn't displaying with flask. I've tried the other answers and nothing is working

Tags: html, css, flask

AS the title says, my background images simply aren't being displayed. My other images are, however. I'm also having an href issue with my links so maybe they're connected? I have my images in my static.css folder, my style sheet in static, and my templates in...you guessed, templates. Here's my css that calls for the background image

```
#banner
{   
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-size: cover; /* or contain depending on what you want */
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what my python code looks like with flask.

```
@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/")
def home():
return render_template("index.html")
```

CSS looks like:

```
#banner
{   
    background-image: url("background.png");
    background-size: cover; /* or contain depending on what you want */
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Not really sure what I did. But if you have the issue I have, then it seems to be an issue with the flask app/routing

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{url_for('static', filename='css/my_image.png')}}`